# why every directory in FTP list has a "dot" item

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am making a JTree that loads files and folder of a FTP Server, using (Apache Commons).
I use this method to load files of a specific directory:

```
FTPFile[] innerFiles = ftp.listFiles();
```

I noticed that for any directory, `innerFiles [0]` is `.` and `innerFiles [1]` is `..`
It is easy to ignore them by start looking from innerFiles[2], but I just want to know what are these reserved items for and would it make any problem in case of ignoring them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files represent the current directory (`.`) and the directory above it (`..`). You should ignore these when creating a tree structure showing all the files and directories.

You could specify a [`FTPFileFilter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFileFilter.html) that strips these out.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore them. Here is an implementation of listing all the actual files, disregarding the two `dot` ones:

```
ftp.listFiles(remoteFilePath, file ->
{
    val filePath = file.getName();
    return !(filePath.equals(".") || filePath.equals(".."));
});
```

This seems more proper than starting with index `2`.